# Facing issues with updateSelectInput function in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shinydashboard, reactive

In the shiny App which I am creating I have a set of Drop down list boxes which are interconnected with each other. That is the input of One drop down box decides the set of Input for others. Kindly find the UI and Server code below.

```
Source_Data <-
data.frame(
key = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
Product_Name = c(
  "Table",
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Table",
  "Bed",
  "Bed",
  "Sofa",
  "Chair",
  "Sofa"
),
Product_desc = c("XX", "XX", "YY", "XX", "Z", "ZZZ", "A", "Y", "AA"),
Cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)
```

The UI and the Server Code

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Demo"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput(
                  "key",
                  "keys",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 3,
                  value = c(1, 3),
                  step = 1
                ),
                selectInput("Product", "List of Products", choices = NULL),
                selectInput("Product_d", "Product Description", choices = NULL),
                actionButton("Button", "ok")
              ),
              mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                type = "tabs",
                tabPanel("table_data", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
              ))

            ))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$key, {
updateSelectInput(session,
                  "Product",
                  "List of Products",
                  choices = unique(
                    Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key) %>% select 
(Product_Name)
                  ))
 })

observeEvent(c(input$key, input$Product), {
updateSelectInput(
  session,
  "Product_d",
  "Product Description",
  choices = unique(
    Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key,
                           Product_Name %in% input$Product) %>% select 
 (Product_desc),
    selected = TRUE
  )
 )

 })

 output_func <- eventReactive(input$Button, {
 key_input <- input$key
 Product_input <- input$Product
 Product_desc_input <- input$Product_d
 cat_input <- input$Product_desc
 div_input <- input$divisions

  z <-
  Source_Data %>% dplyr::arrange (key) %>% dplyr::select(
    key,
    Product_Name,
    Product_Desc,
    Cost
  ) %>% dplyr::filter (
    key %inrange% key_input,
    Product_Name == Product_input,
    Product_Desc == Product_desc_input
  )

   return(z)
  })

output$table_data <-
DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(output_func())
})}


 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue which I am facing is, If a particular product is having only one unique Product description then in the Product Description box that single unique value is not getting displayed.

For example in the Source_data, the Product "Table" has only one unique Product Description "XX". This is not getting displayed in the shiny app. Instead I get the output as the below image.

[image]

Can someone please help me on what mistake I am doing or give any suggestions on how to overcome this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the `unique` function in your observe event seems to fix the problem - now when selecting Table under List of Products the only option available to select under Product Description is "XX".

```
observeEvent(c(input$key, input$Product), {
    updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "Product_d",
        "Product Description",
        choices = 
            Source_Data %>% filter(key %in% input$key,
                                   Product_Name %in% input$Product) %>% 
                select(Product_desc),
            selected = FALSE

    )

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first option to be still selected by default, maybe you can try this:

```
observeEvent(c(input$key, input$Product), {
    updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "Product_d",
        "Product Description",
        choices = unique(
            Source_Data %>% 
                filter(key %in% input$key, Product_Name %in% input$Product) %>% 
                select(Product_desc)
        )[,1]
    )
})
```